# Odd utf 8 error attempting to connect to ms sql server

Tags: python, sql-server, odbc

Connection string set up as follows:

```
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-
import pypyodbc
connection = pypyodbc.connect("DRIVER={SQL Server};SERVER='MyServer';UID='uname';PWD='pwd';DATABASE='mydb'")
```

receiving following error:

```
UnicodeDecodeError: 'utf-32-le' codec can't decode bytes in position 0-1: truncated data
```

Answer (score 0):

What you need to double check is that in the odbc.ini file, the ServerName for the section is the same name in the freetds.conf file.

For instance:

odbc.ini

```
[old_flood]
Driver = FreeTDS
Description = RTS Old Flood
ServerName = old_flood       <----- this must be the same as the name in
freetds.conf
```

freetds.conf

```
[old_flood]                  <----- This is the same as the ServerName above
    host = <server ip address>
    port = <server port>
    tds version = 8.0
```

You also need to make sure the DB user you created has proper access to the Database you are trying to read/write to. For me, I just needed read access. You set this up in the Security node of the SQL Server Management Studio. Right click on the user then go to User Mapping. Check the appropriate databases, make sure to highlight the Database, then at the bottom set the database role.